# IP Forwarding and Routing RPi 2B Jessie

Tags: raspbian-jessie

I am struggling to forward packets from eth0 to eth1 (and back) on my RPi.  I have enabled IP forwarding by adding `net.ipv4.ip_forward=1` in `/etc/sysctl.conf`, and putting an `ip_forward` file containing `1` in `/proc/sys/net/ipv4/`. My IP Tables are set to accept all traffic.

The network is as follows:

PC#1(10.0.0.101 /24 gateway 10.0.0.201) hardwired to RPi eth0(10.0.0.201 /24) theoretically routed to RPi eth1(192.168.1.201 /24) and then hardwired to PC#2 (192.168.1.203 /24). PC#1 has his routing table set properly to send anything destined to the 192.168.1.x LAN through his 10.0.0.101 NIC.

If I ping either the eth0 or eth1 NIC from PC#1 I get good answers, but do not get answers from PC#2.  If I take a cable directly from PC#1 to PC#2, PC#2 answers the ping which tells me that PC#1's routing tables are OK, and that PC#2 is capable of answering a ping request. Additionally, if I'm sitting at the RPi, I can successfully ping PC#1 and PC#2. This only leaves the routing piece of the RPi as the bad guy.  I'm not an expert at Linux and am thinking I'm missing some simple, stupid thing, but I've crawled all over the internet without success.  Any help is greatly appreciated.

Doc

Comment: I'm sure you got your `iptables` wrong. What you're looking for is masquerading.

Comment: why would you use masquerading between two private use nets?

Comment: `PC#1 has his routing table set properly to send anything destined to the 192.168.1.x LAN through his 10.0.0.101 NIC` - does PC#2 routing include 10.0.0.x LAN through 192.168.1.203?

Answer (score 5):

You're doing stuff wrong.

1. <s>You should only place `net.ipv4.ip_forward=1` in `/etc/sysctl.conf`. Do ***NOT*** modify files in the `/proc` folder.</s> It's okay, just be careful.
2. You are simply accepting traffic and you only allowed forwarding. It can forward traffic but you didn't tell it to forward traffic.

---

**Try this:** 
First, put `net.ipv4.ip_forward=1` in `/etc/sysctl.conf`. Then reboot.

An alternative, if you don't want to reboot, is to run (as root) `echo 1> /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward`

Then, flush your entire iptables.

```
iptables -F
iptables -X
iptables -t nat -F
iptables -t nat -X
iptables -t mangle -F
iptables -t mangle -X
iptables -P INPUT ACCEPT
iptables -P FORWARD ACCEPT
iptables -P OUTPUT ACCEPT
```

Then, masquerade the traffic, assuming `eth1` is the output. Change it accordingly.

```
# Allow established connections
iptables -A INPUT -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
iptables -A FORWARD -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT

# Masquerade
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth1 -j MASQUERADE
```

Then, save it using `iptables-save > /etc/iptables/rules.v4`

To restore, simply run `iptables-restore < /etc/iptables/rules.v4`

As an added bonus, you can add the command on `/etc/network/interfaces` so you don't have to manually run the restore command every boot. Modify that file so it looks like

```
# ...

auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
# your configuration and stuff
post-up iptables-restore < /etc/iptables/rules.v4     # The line you need to add

# ...
```

Comment: `Do it on both Pi routers` - did you read a different question? There's only one Pi in the question ... `the "WAN" side` ... there is no WAN in the question either

Comment: @JaromandaX corrected. I thought there were two Pis. Realized there was one pi with two interfaces.

Comment: @JaromandaX I just realized my answer is totally different than the question.

Comment: Thanks PandaLion98.  I did everything as per your suggestions, but, alas, I still cannot get from one network to the other across the RPi.  I grabbed another SD card I had lying around with a Wheezy distro on it, and am having no better luck.  I must be missing something.  Among the things bothering me, is the fact that the RPi will answer pings to either of his NICs regardless of the NIC that it comes in on.  I would expect this behavior with IP Forwarding enabled, but I'm getting whether forwarding is enabled or not.  I think I'm gonna try another RPi just to be sure I don't have a bad RPi.

Comment: Your pi is most probably okay.

Comment: @AutoDoc Do you have a plain-old regular router?

Comment: @PandaLion98, I tried different hardware with the same results (as expected).  And yes, I do have a router lying around here somewhere, but  I need some processing power for the end game of this project.  I work for a small PLC-based machine manufacturer and am trying to come up with a VPN-based remote troubleshooting piece so our techs don't have to hop on a plane every time a machine burps.  There are commercial "black box" products out there, but start at $500 and go north from there.  I have solved this problem using a small PC, but that cost is still about $250. I'm trying to get to $100.

Comment: @AutoDoc You will want to read this: http://serverfault.com/q/745711/273852