# Use the RPi3 with Libreelec to route between 2 networks

Tags: networking, iptables

I'm using Libreelec on a RPi3 and I would like to use it to route between *eth0* and *wlan0* too.

- Network A - **192.168.0.0**/24 with Internet access, connected to *eth0*, my network
- Network B - **192.168.1.0**/24 with Internet access, connected to *wlan0*, friend's network

Basically I would like to "merge" the two networks with the Pi, so I can access my friend's network (just for file sharing directly, not for Internet access) and he can access mine whenever the Pi is switched on. Consider these sample devices:

- **Router_A** = IP 192.168.0.1 + DHCP server (192.168.0.50-250) + Static route (192.168.1.0 MASK 255.255.255.0 192.168.0.**112** METRIC 2)
- **PC_A** = IP 192.168.0.77 (reseved on DHCP of *Router_A*), received default gateway 192.168.0.1
- **RPi** ***eth0*** = IP 192.168.0.**112** (reserved on DHCP of *Router_A*), received default gateway 192.168.0.1
- **RPi** ***wlan0*** = IP 192.168.1.**253** (reserved on DHCP of *Router_B*), doesn't seem to receive the default gateway even though *Router_B* provides it (and this should be correct, as *eth0* is primary, right?)
- **PC_B** = IP 192.168.1.99 (reserved on DHCP of *Router_B*), received default gateway 192.168.1.1 + Static route (192.168.0.0 MASK 255.255.255.0 192.168.1.**253** METRIC 2)
- **Router_B** = IP 192.168.1.1 + DHCP server (192.168.1.50-250), doesn't handle static routes so I had to add one to *PC_B*

[image: Network layout]

After connecting to my RPi via SSH and typing these commands (read from [here](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/40563/ip-forwarding-and-routing-rpi-2b-jessie/40575#40575)):

```
LibreELEC:~/downloads # echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward
LibreELEC:~/downloads # iptables -F
LibreELEC:~/downloads # iptables -X
LibreELEC:~/downloads # iptables -t nat -F
LibreELEC:~/downloads # iptables -t nat -X
LibreELEC:~/downloads # iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o wlan0 -j MASQUERADE
```

... from *PC_A* and every other device on the network **A** I'm able to ping and connect to any PC or device on network **B**.

My issue is that **the reverse is not true**: from *PC_B* I **can't ping** *PC_A* or *Router_A*, only *RPI wlan0*. But *PC_B* has the static route added manually! Of course from the RPi via SSH I can ping any device on both networks.

What's wrong? I'm pretty sure something in *iptables* is missing, but I'm unable to figure out what, in particular.

NOTE: I don't need NAT specifically, this is the only setup that I've found working at the moment.

### EDIT:

After *Ingo* answered, I learned the following which may be useful for future readers:

1. The configuration was correct and only the *ip_forward* setting is necessary to make it work. NAT masquerade (last command) is not required.
2. If from *RPi* you're not able to ping *PC_B* check that the [firewall has the correct rule](https://www.faqforge.com/windows/windows-10/how-to-allow-ping-trough-the-firewall-in-windows-10/) on *PC_B* or disable the firewall.
3. Even after allowing ping on the firewall (previous point), from *PC_A* you won't be able to ping *PC_B* (but *RPi* will ping *PC_B*). However, if from *PC_A* you try to reach a port opened on *PC_B* (such as a webserver) it will work; ping is not working due to the firewall of *PC_B* (if you disable it, ping will work too). Alternatively, you can enable NAT masquerading (last command) and in this way *PC_A* will ping *PC_B* even without disabling the firewall.
4. When creating the manual static route on *PC_B* it doesn't matter if the priority number in `route print` is higher than the gateway route on Windows 10. It's just a visualization (wrong in my opinion).
5. My issues were caused by something on *Network B* that I haven't identified yet (see comments below).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a bit effortful to follow only your textual description so I do not follow it in detail. But you are using network address translation (NAT). This only works in one direction, from the "inside" PC to the "outside" world. The outside devices cannot reach the inside PC. This principle is used on any internet router and also a security issue. You should check your setup, if the reverse connections that does not work have to pass the NAT backwards. This is not possible due to the nature of the address translation.

**UPDATE** regarding to your drawing:
Very informative picture now :) Looks very good so far, can't find big issues, except the NAT. Just omit setting the NAT using iptables. But you need ip forwarding with `echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward`. Don't touch that. There is no gateway shown at the **wlan0** interface on the RasPi. That's correct. The RasPi should only use one gateway (default route) on interface **eth0** to its internet router 192.168.0.1. There is a static route set on PC_B whith `route add 19.168.0.0 MASKI 255.255.255.0 192.168.1.253 METRIC 2`. There is nothing wrong with it, but it's better to set this route on Router_B as you did on Router_A. This is a more general routing. Otherwise you have to set the static route on every device on Network B, that should connect to Network A.

Comment: I've tried to do my best to explain the network (will try to add an image soon), anyway I don't need a NAT (it's not mandatory) so I can remove it if I found a way to do in another way. Can you suggest something that does the routing forward and backward that I can try?

Comment: @virtualdj Yes, I respect your effort to explain the network and I've upvoted it. But I have to translate the words into a picture in my mind and that isn't done at a glance ... A simple picture says more than thousand words. I'm confident that we will find a solution.

Comment: Thanks, I've edited the question with the graphical network diagram and a  note about not needing NAT.

Comment: @virtualdj I have updated the answer.

Comment: I know it's better to set the route on _Router_B_ but unfortunately that router doesn't allow to :-( After your message, I tried to replicate the _Network B_ configuration using another router and PC that I own and indeed it works... But not on my friend's setup. Probably there's something wrong there, but apart from the manual route to be set on the PC there is nothing more, right? I'll have to try again.

Comment: It seems a problem of my friend's network: on my "simulated" network it works correctly, while my friend's network with the same route command **does not**! I opened [another question for this](https://serverfault.com/q/1011349/342594) on ServerFault.

Comment: @virtualdj Is the answer for Raspberry Pi acceptable?